Cross-checking strings from 2 different columns
I have the following columns from 2 tables with customers' allergens and food recipes. I want to cross-check both columns to see which customers asked for recipes containing their allergens.
I cannot quite figure how to do it. The following code isn't working for me, it reflects no findings, as if there was no match of values between both columns. Could anyone lend me a hand? Thanks!

This is what I tried:
SELECT customer.allergens, recipe.ingredients
FROM recipe
JOIN orders ON recipe.id = orders.recipe_id
JOIN customer ON orders.customer_id = customer.id
WHERE customer.allergens LIKE recipe.ingredients

Also a bit more rudimentary but still doesn't yield good results.
SELECT customer.allergens, recipe.ingredients
FROM recipe
JOIN orders ON recipe.id = orders.recipe_id
JOIN customer ON orders.customer_id = customer.id
WHERE recipe.ingredients LIKE '%fish%' 
   OR recipe.ingredients LIKE '%pork%' 
   OR recipe.ingredients LIKE '%mayo%' 
   OR recipe.ingredients LIKE '%almonds%'

I was expecting to see a match, so if "almond" is in both columns, this is reflected in the query.

Hi - please don't link to images. Update your question to show 1) table definitions 2) sample data 3) the result you want to achieve. All as editable text appropriately formatted (code as code, data as tables, etc)

Using %% is a really costly query and should be avoided if possible.
You could instead do a link table, linking to a new table with all the ingredients. so a recipe id 1 is connected through a "link table"
so table: Recipe has an entry:
id   recipename
1    chicken masala

Then you have the new table called: Ingredients
   id   ingredientname
   1    chicken
   2    rice
   3    beef
   4    masala spice

and then the link table: recipe-ingredient-link has these three connections.
   recipeid   ingredientid
   1          1
   1          2
   1          4

Thus connecting the recipe 1 to ingredients 1,2 and 4. (and not to 3 which is beef)
THEN you make another link table connecting people/allergens to the same ingredient table: person-allergen-link
   personid   allergenid  (allergenid=ingredientid in the table, just to clarify)
   1          3
   2          1

So person 1 can eat Chicken masala because he is allergic to beef which is not in the recipe, but person 2 cannot as he is allergic to chicken.
Then you can much faster get all the foods not in the ids that a person is allergic to. Example select:
select * from recipe r join recipe-ingredient-link ril on r.recipeid=ril.recipeid where ril.ingredientid not in (select allergenid from person-allergen-link where personid=[the id of the person doing the search])

This will get all the recipes that does not include the allergens of that person. You could easily add another variable to show only recipes that includes a specific ingredient along with the allergens...
